# Why does Pandas inconsistently use a MultiIndex when doing a groupby on an empty DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Even if a DataFrame has zero rows, I would expect a `groupby` to still return a result with a MultiIndex that reflects the groupby columns. However, in some cases, this does not happen. For example, in the following code, the index has no name and is not a MultiIndex.

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[None,None], 'col2':[None,None], 'col3':[None,None]})
display(foo.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'col3':'sum'}))
```

On the other hand, a MultiIndex (with the correct level names) will exist if I change any of the columns' type to a non-object type. Furthermore, when grouping by a single column, I get an index with the correct name even if the types are still all Object.

Is this behavior intentional? What is the philosophy behind when a MultiIndex is used?

Answer (score 0):

Try `dropna = False`:

```
foo.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], dropna=False).agg({'col3':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
           col3
col1 col2      
NaN  NaN      0
```

Comment: I tried that, with the following results: `groupby` doesn't take a `dropna` argument. Adding `dropna` to `agg` makes no difference.

Comment: Can you upgrade your pandas version? (dropna New in version 1.1.0.)